# Creating a storage "collection" for each month in PSQL?

Tags: c#, database, triggers, psql

I want to make a trigger or some kind of event over PSQL database that will trigger on end of the month and store data from one table (constrains data for each employee, when he came and went home from work each day) inside some kind of collection (database) of tables so I can still reach for that data if Im making monthly reports ( PSQL is the database, C# is used to make application). Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a very pressing need to separate that data out, just leave it in the tables where it is. You don't usually need to archive-out old data in a database, just write queries that select data created since start-of-month etc.

If you must do an archive and summarize process, use a cron or task scheduler job that invokes a plpgsql procedure to do appropriate `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` and `DELETE FROM` queries for your tables. There's no generic way to do it.

If what you're looking for is table partitioning, there are tools like pgpartman for that. But you probably don't need it if you just tune your queries/indexes a bit.

Comment: so your saying its better to use filters in the app forms then sorting data in separate tables? My only concern is will it make bottle necks in connection and in reaching data from database after for ex. 2 years have passed? If my calculations are correct there should be cca 21,000 rows in that table at the end of the year.

Comment: It's *definitely* better to use filters in SQL than separate tables. 21000 rows is hilariously tiny, like "you don't even need indexes" tiny. If you had millions of rows you'd need to pay more attention, but still probably wouldn't need to partition the table.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and heads up, appreciate it =)